# ExpandoObject in Nemerle

Tags: .net, variables, dynamic, expandoobject, nemerle

AFAIK Nemerle doesn't have `dynamic` keyword, late binding doesn't work as well:

```
late{
        mutable obj=ExpandoObject();   
        obj.test="test"; //MissingMethodException
    }
```

So, is there a way to use ExpandoObject in Nemerle?

Answer (score 1):

"late" use reflection and can't work with ExpandoObject.

But you can use ExpandoObject like Dictionary:

```
def obj = ExpandoObject() : IDictionary[string, object];
obj["test"] = 42;
WriteLine(obj["test"]);
```

What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I would use dictionary if I wanted to, I'm just interested if I can use ExpandoObject like it's intended to: `dynamic obj=new ExpandoObject();obj.test="test";`

Comment: 'dynamic' is not supported in Nemerle right now.
It can be implemented but no one needed it.